# Indexedb on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, indexeddb

I wonder if any of you can help me with this?  I have developed a web application that uses an indexed database with 95 object stores.  The DB installs fine on Chrome, but usually produces an error on IE (where I would like to get it running for reasons I won't discuss here).  The problem is the creating of 95 object stores in the onUpgrade routine (even if I put no data in them).  Here is an example of the code:

```
encode (NoofCKlistItems,"NoofCKlistItems");
 encode (pgtxt,"pgtxt");
 //there are 95 statements like the ones above

   function encode(j_ThisField,StoreName) {
        objectStore = dbInterview.createObjectStore(StoreName);
        for (i in j_ThisField) { 
        itemnumber =  parseInt(j_ThisField[i][0], 10);   
        objectStore.put(j_ThisField[i][1],itemnumber); }
        }
```

I cannot think of a way round this. I have tried chaining the 95 calls to the encode function with callbacks, but no change.  I have tried putting a delay in the end of the encode function, but then it loses the transaction.  The only things that reliably work are (a) to halve the number of object stores, or (b) to put an alert at the end of the encode function, so the program has to stop at every variable (so you have to click 95 times!).

I have not found a way of adding to the object stores once the DB is installed.  An upgrade event removes everything and starts again, so the problem remains.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Steve Moss

Comment: Can you post a *runnable* example?  Even if you just make a loop that generates 95 sequential `StoreName`s?

Comment: Wouldn't be a shock if it's just a limitation in IE, their IndexedDB implementation is pretty buggy.

Comment: Hi Jeremy.  Thanks for the idea.  I previously tried a loop counter as you suggested, but it didn't help.  I will see if I can post something runnable over the weekend.  Steve Moss

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.  I simply put a check at the end of the encode routine, to see if the last of the 95 variables is being written to the indexeddb.  If it is the last one, an alert is fired to say the download is complete.  This seems to give IE the breathing space it needs to finish processing. So the encode routine becomes:

```
function encode(j_ThisField,StoreName) {
        objectStore = dbInterview.createObjectStore(StoreName);
        for (i in j_ThisField) { 
        itemnumber =  parseInt(j_ThisField[i][0], 10);   
        objectStore.put(j_ThisField[i][1],itemnumber); }
        counter++;
        if (StoreName===<THE LAST VARIABLE NAME>){alert('complete');}
        }
```

It works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed a crucial line.  I also had to add an alert when the counter has reached 45.  This relates to having found that IE copes with half of the 90 variables, but not the whole 90.  So the encode routine is:

```
function encode(j_ThisField,StoreName) {
        objectStore = dbInterview.createObjectStore(StoreName);
        for (i in j_ThisField) { 
        itemnumber =  parseInt(j_ThisField[i][0], 10);   
        objectStore.put(j_ThisField[i][1],itemnumber); }
        counter++;
        if (counter===45){alert('Click to continue dowloading');}
        if (StoreName===<THE LAST VARIABLE NAME>){alert('Click to complete the download');}
        }
```

Thanks for your suggestions